# Rails voice/chat plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been looking around in Google, but haven't found an answer. Do you guys know any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily implement a chat with socky as seen today in one of the Lightin Talks by Bernard "Imanel" Potocki at Euruko conference in Krakow (Poland):

check this: http://github.com/imanel/socky_example

Comment: If voice is a proirity for you, these guys http://adhearsion.com/ often present voice solutions that integrate into rails apps. The were on last two EuRuKo's talking about it. Google for a video of their talks or write to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.raydash.com. Take a look at the gem Readme at https://github.com/gersh/Raydash-Ruby-on-Rails. Take a look at the view helpers at https://github.com/gersh/Raydash-Ruby-on-Rails/blob/master/lib/app/helpers/raydash_helper.rb. You can hide the video if you want, and just do voice.

You can input audio and stream it via flash.

Comment: You are starting to attract lots of flags for your answers where you are suggesting this product.  I've removed a couple of these because they were about to be removed as spam by the system (as well as 100 of your rep points).  Per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion)  `"Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion[. Y]ou must disclose your affiliation in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons."`